# New Eclipse: Error while downloading 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd' to C:\Users\Fabian.Meier\.lsp4xml\

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-2020-03

I have installed Eclipse 2020-3 and now facing the error

```
Error while downloading 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd' to C:\Users\Fabian.Meier\.lsp4xml\cache\http\maven.apache.org\xsd\maven-4.0.0.xsd.
```

on every POM. At other places it was suggested to configure the proxy correctly.

But our proxy just does not allow Eclipse to connect to the internet at all.

Can I use my Eclipse offline without facing the error above?

Comment: Does the project build correctly on plain command line?

Comment: Yes, no problem with that. It is just an annoying error message. It seems you can "solve" it by manually downloading the file and putting it in the right place. But when we give the new Eclipse version to our 100+ developers, I would like to avoid telling them that they need to copy around files by hand...

Comment: Have you tried to change into `https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Where do I need to configure that?

Comment: In the XML prefix of the pom file? (Hopefully your own?)...The cached seemed to be from  https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx ? ...

Comment: Seeing the same issue, except it uses `.lemminx` as cache directory instead of `.lsp4xml`.  Tried setting proxy, but even then it just doesn't want to download it.  The url downloads fine with `curl`.  If only it gave a more informative error message...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to disable Language Server errors : into Preferences -> Language Servers and turn them all off.

Comment: For me it was enough just disabling XML.

Comment: Good job, this worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable Language Server errors : into Preferences -> Language Servers and turn them all off. -- this worked for me.

Comment: This is the same answer as above. Therefore, it should be deleted.